Unable to delete directory while doing gradle clean build
Unable to delete directory 'D:\user\random-project\build'
Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has 
files open or has its 
working directory set in the target directory.
- D:\user\random-project\build\tmp\.cache\expanded\expanded.lock
- D:\user\random-project\build\tmp\.cache\expanded
- D:\user\random-project\build\tmp\.cache
- D:\user\random-project\build\tmp


I manually deleted the build file, still it is not able to build.
Gradle clean build does not work but gradle clean works

My guess is Windows is being stupid, try restarting the machine so it releases whatever locks i has on whatever files

(1) Check if any file manager is opening this directory: D:\user\random-project\build\tmp  (2) Check if there is cmd.exe in this directory or below
Table of contents. (3) Close all open file explorers and cmd.exe or powershell.

I tried both the way but they're not working for me. Is there any other alternative?

show your gradle build file

i've added the image of what my build file looks like. above

Finally, uninstalling and re-installing the IDE worked for me
